# Prove that the image of $\varphi$ , $\varphi(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

let $G$ and $H$ be groups and let $\varphi : G \to H$ be  a homomorphism.Prove that the image  of $\varphi$ , $\varphi(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$ .

My attempt : To  show the image  of $\varphi$ , $\varphi(G)$ is a subgroup of $H $

It is given that $\varphi :G \to H$ is  a homomorphism and  $\varphi (G)$ denote the image of $\varphi$.

Now we will used the lagrange theorem's  because  $\varphi$ is homomorphism

let $ y\in \varphi(G)$ and  $g\in G$.Then  $y^{-1} = \varphi(g)^{-1}=\varphi(g^{-1})\in \varphi (G)$

$y^{-1}= \varphi(g^{-1}) $ This implies that  $\varphi(G)$ is satisfying  the lagrange theorem

Therefore $\varphi (G)$ is a  subgroup of $H$

Comment: What is the Lagrange theorem?

Comment: @ChrisCuster see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)

Comment: Yes, well that's why I asked.  I'm certainly familiar with it.  But it begins with "if $H$ is a subgroup...".  I don't see how it can be used to _show_ that you have a subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write "let $y\in\varphi(G)$ and $g\in G$," you have taken arbitrary elements in both the image of $\varphi$ and in $G$. What you want is to start with an arbitrary $y\in\varphi(G)$, which by definition is equal to $\varphi(x)$ for *some* $x\in G$. This is an important distinction that is easy to miss. Then proceed as you were: $\varphi(x^{-1})\varphi(y)=\varphi(x^{-1}y)=\varphi(1)=1$, and similarly $\varphi(y)\varphi(x^{-1})=1$, which shows $\varphi(x^{-1})=y^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the subgroup criterion: $\varphi(G)\ne\emptyset$ and $x,y\in \varphi(G)\implies xy^{-1}\in\varphi(G)$?

---

Or, you could use the first isomorphism theorem, which tells us that the image is isomorphic to $G/\rm{ker}\varphi$.  $\ker\varphi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, so the quotient is indeed a group.

Comment: yes  sir ,@Chris Custer   u r right $xy^{-1} \varphi (G)$